# Как узнать все элементы блока к которым не была применена jquery функция hide()

Tags: jquery

Я делаю так:

```
    var total = 0;
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.item-price').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('display')=='visible') {
            total = total + Math.round($(this).find('span').text());
            console.log(total);
        }
    });
```

но ничего не получается :(

Comment: должно быть не `$(this).css('display')=='visible'`, а  `$(this).css('display') != 'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить `:visible`

```
    var total = 0;
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.item-price:visible').each(function(){
            total = total + Math.round($(this).find('span').text());
            console.log(total);
    });
```

Comment: @amijin, да, конечно... Спасибо